# Is there a selector similar to general sibling selector that does not need elements to have the same parent?

Tags: html, css

I am building a japanese learning site (and i am a total beginner with css and html etc.) with wordpress and want to add a kana-helper:  Every time when the cursor hovers over a kana (basic japanese characters) in the text, the belonging romaji should be shown in a fixed div.
This is a simplified version of what i have so far (thx to the help of this community):

```css
/*working, but only when in same parent*/
.ko:hover ~ .kanahelfer-ko {display: block;}
/*not working, because not same paren?*/
.re:hover ~ .kanahelfer-re {display: block;}
/*not working because ???*/
.ha:hover .kanahelfer-ha {display: block;}
/*how to get it working?*/

.kanahelfer-ko{
       display: none;
       position: fixed;
       left: 28px;
       top: 120px;
       height: 160px; 
       width: 160px;
       color: black;
}

.kanahelfer-re{ 
       position: fixed;
       left: 28px;
       top: 120px;
       display: none;
       height: 160px; 
       width: 160px;
       color: black;
}

.kanahelfer-ha{ 
       position: fixed;
       left: 28px;
       top: 120px;
       display: none;
       height: 160px; 
       width: 160px;
       color: black;
}
```

```html
<span class="ko">こ</span><span class="re">れ</span><span class="ha">は</span>

<div class="kanahelfer-ko">
    <div class="kana">ko</div> 
</div>

<div>
<div class="kanahelfer-re">
    <div class="kana">re</div> 
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="kanahelfer-ha">
  <div class="kana">ha/Partike wa</div> 
</div>
```

Problem is, that there are over 200 different kana und the text with the japanese letters is in a table and so i would have to make over 200 entries per table cell (too much) if i will not find a working solution. Is there a selector or way to achieve this with css and html only, even when elements are not in the same parent? (If not, i would have to learn js -.-). I do not understand why `.ha:hover .kanahelfer-ha {display: block;}` does not work.

Comment: because ".re:hover ~ .kanahelfer-ha {display: block;}" does work and both are to my understanding (as i said, i am a beginner)  selectors: with ~one selects general siblings, without it, one should select everything with class="kanahelfer-ha"

Comment: Quite simply...no. There is **no** css selector that allows you to go upwards in the DOM which is what is required here (you have to go up first before down again). You need javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated your snippet and add some JavaScript.

1. You need to link JQuery to make this code working.
2. You need to put all the JS code into ready event handler:

   ```
   $(function() {
      // JS code
   });
   ```
3. `$('.letters')` – finding all elements with `letters` class.
4. `this` – current object (clicked in this particular case).
5. `$(this).data('letter')` – gets a value from `data-letter` attribute.

```js
// Taking all ".letter" in ".letters" and bind an event handler to "hover" event
$('.letters .letter').hover(function () {
  // Get a letter from hovered element
  var letter = $(this).data('letter');
  // Show just necessary element  
  $('.kanahelfer-' + letter).show();
}).
// Bind an event handler for "mouseleave" event
mouseleave(function() {
  // Hide all ".kanahelfer" elements
  $('.kanahelfer').hide();
});
```

```css
.kanahelfer-ko{
       display: none;
       position: fixed;
       left: 28px;
       top: 120px;
       height: 160px; 
       width: 160px;
       color: black;
}

.kanahelfer-re{ 
       position: fixed;
       left: 28px;
       top: 120px;
       display: none;
       height: 160px; 
       width: 160px;
       color: black;
}

.kanahelfer-ha{ 
       position: fixed;
       left: 28px;
       top: 120px;
       display: none;
       height: 160px; 
       width: 160px;
       color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kana-container">
  <div class="letters">
  <span class="letter" data-letter="ko">こ</span><span class="letter" data-letter="re">れ</span><span class="letter" data-letter="ha">は</span>
  </div>

<div class="kanahelfer kanahelfer-ko">
    <div class="kana">ko</div> 
</div>

<div>
<div class="kanahelfer kanahelfer-re">
    <div class="kana">re</div> 
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="kanahelfer kanahelfer-ha">
  <div class="kana">ha/Partike wa</div> 
</div>
</div>
```